# What is the difference between executing and sourcing scripts in R

Tags: r

A basic question as I am starting out R.

What is the main difference when I am sourcing a R script vs executing it?
I am trying to get ggplot2 example scripts running.

```
library("ggplot2")

d = data.frame(x1=c(1,3,1,5,4), x2=c(2,4,3,6,6), y1=c(1,1,4,1,3), y2=c(2,2,5,3,5), t=c('a','a','a','b','b'), r=c(1,2,3,4,5))
ggplot() +
scale_x_continuous(name="x") +
scale_y_continuous(name="y") +
geom_rect(data=d, mapping=aes(xmin=x1, xmax=x2, ymin=y1, ymax=y2, fill=t),color="black",alpha=0.5) +
geom_text(data=d, aes(x1+(x2-x1)/2,y=y1+(y2-y1)/2, label=r), size=4) +
opts(title="geom_rect", plot.title=theme_text(size=40, vjust=1.5))
```

When I source this script, no plots appear. I understand this has to do with lack of explicit print statement in my code. I've read a discussion that when you execute a command in the interactive shell, the print statement is implicit.

My question is this - When I execute a script vs source it, what is the basic difference?
When would I do one over another? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems likely to be related to The R-FAQ in section 7 relating to why grid based graphics do not get plotted. Try using explicit `print` or `plot` command.

Reading the first sentence of "Details" in the help page for `source` to you:

`Details

Note that running code via source differs in a few respects from entering it at the R command line. Since expressions are not executed at the top level, auto-printing is not done.`  (And I'm glad to see that you did read the rest of that section.)

Comment: Hey, thanks. But, I want to understand the difference between sourcing and executing the script. I think executing the script is similar to running a command in the interactive console, hence explicit print is not necessary. But, is that true?

Comment: No, it's not true. `source` is a function. Did your read the FAQ?

Comment: You are right. This is what the help section says about source -> "source causes R to accept its input from the named file or URL or connection. Input is read and parsed from that file until the end of the file is reached, then the parsed expressions are evaluated sequentially in the chosen environment."  I think what you are hinting at is, it is being evaluated, but not printed. Did I understand it right?

Comment: it's not _quite_ generic to grid-based graphics; just those that use a `print` method (marginal difference, I know).